# Отключился скрипт JS в расширении к Google Сhrome

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome, расширения

Делаю расширения для хрома.

манифест:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "My First Extension",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

popup.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">


  <body>
 <p id="f">hello</p>
 <script>
let a=[
[1,2,3,"CE"],
[4,5,6,"+"],
[7,8,9,"-"],
["*","/","x2","sqrt(x)"],
]
let op1=[];
let op2=[];
var actStr="";
function goschit(e){
    
    if ("1234567890".includes(e)){
        actStr+=e;
        op1.push(actStr);
        document.getElementById("f").innerHTML=op1[op1.length-1];
    }
    
    }
    
var table = document.createElement('table');
document.body.appendChild(table);
for(let i=0;i<4;i+=1){
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    table.appendChild(tr);
    for(let j=0;j<4;j+=1){
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        tr.appendChild(td);
        var btn = document.createElement('button');
        btn.id = 'btid';
        btn.onclick=function(){goschit(a[i][j])};
        var textInBtn = document.createTextNode(a[i][j]);
        btn.appendChild(textInBtn);
        td.appendChild(btn);
    }
} 
</script>

 
  </body>
 
</html>
```

в итоге:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

хотя на обычной странице так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне кажется что полностью отключается скрипт JS. Как исправить? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Попробуй js перместить в отдельный файл и подправить манифест. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#declaratively. Скипты, который отрабатывают в popup.html и в браузере пользователя, подключаются в манифесте по-разному

Comment: теперь выдаёт ошибку Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem:".

Comment: что такого сделал "eval"!?